# Get all field with distinct where clause and order

Tags: android, sqlite

I am implementing a messenger function for my android app and save every received and sent message in the following sqlite schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (
`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
`message_id` TEXT, 
`sentTimestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
`senderUserID` TEXT, 
`senderUsername` TEXT, 
`senderProfilePictureUrl` TEXT, 
`receiverUserID` TEXT, 
`receiverUsername` TEXT, 
`message` TEXT)
```

Now I want to have an overview about all my chats (like in WhatsApp) with the repective last message received or sent. I need all fields (SELECT *). The problem is that every chat partner must only appear once and if I was the last sender my last message should appear on the list.

**Example:**

1. User *other* sends "How are you?" to user *me*.
2. User *me* sends "I am good" to user *other*.

**Expected result:**

```
+----------+-------------+
|    User  |  Message    |
+----------+-------------+
| other    | I am good   |
+----------+-------------+
```

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT * FROM "+MESSAGE_TABLE+" 
GROUP BY senderUserID, receiverUserID 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

but the result looks like this:

```
+--------------+----------------+
|    User      |  Message       |
+--------------+----------------+
| other        | How are you?   |
| me           | I am good      |
+--------------+----------------+
```

How can I achieve this? Is this even possible with just 1 table so that I cannot make joins?

Comment: mention which RDBMS you are using

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

do like :

```
SELECT * FROM "+MESSAGE_TABLE+" where senderUserID NOT IN (SELECT distinct receiverUserID from "+MESSAGE_TABLE+")
GROUP BY senderUserID, receiverUserID 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are double user ids as well.